# Change Seekbar color

Tags: android, xml

I want to change `SeekBar` color, precisely I want to change color of dot that is dragged to change the progress value. I know I can do it by changing "colorAccent" value but that's not what I'm up to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The dot you're refering to is called the SeekBar Thumb. To change the color of the Seekbar thumb, create a new style in `style.xml`

**Change Via XML**

```
<SeekBar
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:thumbTint="your_color"  //gives your color
android:thumb="@drawable/yourseekthumb"  //gives your drawable
android:theme="@style/SeekBarColor" />
```

You can either give your color using `thumbTint` or your drawable using `android:thumb`.

This method works for API>16.

**To change SeekBar thumb color by Java code**

```
SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
seekbar.getThumb().setColorFilter(your_color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

This method works for only android 5 and above.

Comment: When I add thumbTint the color changes in Android Studio but not in emulator, whereas when I add new thumb drawable the thumb disappears (I added xml oval)

Comment: If color doesn't change in emulator on using thumbTint, try using a real device. Also try using the Java code and see if it works. If the problem still persists, please add the relevant code in your question as an edit.

Comment: Was the issue resolved?

Comment: Using real device helped :) thank you

Comment: Glad to help! Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

try this
 Just use `android:thumbTint="@color/colorPrimary"` in your seekbar.

like this

```
<SeekBar
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:max="100"
     android:thumbTint="@color/red"
     android:progress="0" />
```

**you can change the thum like this of your seekbar**

```
Drawable seekbarThumb = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.seekbarThumb );
SeekBar mySeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mySeekBar );
mySeekBar .setThumb(seekbarThumb );
```